# Interesting binomial coefficients sum: $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^b(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Any idea on whether or not $$\sum_{i = 0}^b(-1)^i\binom{b}{i}\binom{a+b-i-1}{a-i}$$
has a closed formula on $a$ and $b$ (and on what it is, in case it does)?

It is supposed that $b \le a$.

Comment: Isn't it zero everytime?

Comment: Yes, @thinkingeye. I wrote it wrongly: the summation stops at $b$, not at $a$.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be zero as well...

Comment: Where did you get it from?

Comment: I wanted to calculate $$\sum_{i = 0}^{a_2-1}\int_0^1\frac{\lambda^it^{a_1-1+i}(1-t)^{b_1-1}(1-\lambda t)^{b_2}}{(b_2+i)B(i+1, b_2)}dt,$$ where $B$ is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: So I wrote $(1-\lambda t)^{b_2}$ as a summation and used the formula for the integral of $t^a(1-t)^b$ from $0$ to $1$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: After that, we end up with a doble sum with indexes $i$ and $j$. I switched to a sum over $s := i+j$ and $j$, replacing $i$ with $s-j$.

Comment: Oh, I see the mistake I made. In the last step, I disregard the fact that $j$'s value is at least $s-(a_2-1)$.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Gould's combinatorial identities eq (3.49).

Comment: Cross posted here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376606/binomial-coefficients-sum

Comment: [Searching with Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%20%3D%200%7D%5Eb(-1)%5Ei%5Cbinom%7Bb%7D%7Bi%7D%5Cbinom%7Ba%2Bb-i-1%7D%7Ba-i%7D%24&amp;p=1) leads [this AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h16482p114715). It also links to Exercise 4 in [this problem set](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/17f/hw4os.pdf) from Darij Grinberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a combinatorial proof that the expression is $0$.  Both sides of the identity count the number of $(b-1)$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,a+b-1\}$ that include $\{1,\dots,b\}$.  Because $b > b-1$, this count is obviously $0$, establishing the RHS.  For the LHS, apply inclusion-exclusion, where the $b$ properties to be avoided are that $j$ does not appear for $j \in \{1,\dots,b\}$.  More generally, this argument shows that
$$\sum_{i=0}^b (-1)^i \binom{b}{i} \binom{a+b-1-i}{k} = 0$$
for $k < b$, and it does not require $b \le a$.

Comment: Awesome, @RobPratt! I'm choosing your answer for its beauty and its clarity.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{i = 0}^{b}\pars{-1}^{i}
{b \choose i}{a + b - i - 1 \choose a - i}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{i = 0}^{b}\pars{-1}^{i}
{b \choose i}\bracks{z^{a - i}}
\pars{1 + z}^{a + b - i - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{a}}\pars{1 + z}^{a + b - 1}\sum_{i = 0}^{b}
{b \choose i}\pars{-\,{z \over 1 + z}}^{i}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{a}}\pars{1 + z}^{a + b - 1}\,\,
\pars{1 - {z \over 1 + z}}^{b}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{a}}\pars{1 + z}^{a - 1} =
\bbx{\large 0} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Awesome, @Felix! Thank you!

Comment: @Valentino Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if $a=0,$ you get $1.$
Assume now $a>0.$ Notice that if $i=0$ you are evaluating $\binom{a+b-1}{b-1}$ this is the number of ways to write $a$ as a sum of $b$ $(x_1,\cdots ,x_b)$ non-negative integers by the stars and bars technique.
Consider now the following sets $$A_i = \{(x_1,\cdots ,x_b):\sum _{j=1}^bx_j=a , \, x_i\geq 1\},$$
notice that at all possible ways have to be such that at least one of the $x_j\geq 1$ hence, by the principle of inclusion-exclusion,
$$\binom{a+b-1}{b-1}=\left |\bigcup _{i=1}^b A_i\right |=\sum _{i=1}(-1)^{i-1}\sum _{Y\in \binom{[b]}{i}}\left |\bigcap _{y\in Y}A_y\right |.$$
Notice, further, that $|\cap _{y\in Y}A_y|=\binom{a-|Y|+b-1}{b-1}$ because all the $x_y\geq 1$ so you can redefine $z_y=x_y-1$ and pass the $|Y|$ 1's to the other side of the equation. So you get that
$$\binom{a+b-1}{b-1}=\sum _{i=1}^b(-1)^{i-1}\binom{b}{i}\binom{a-i+b-1}{b-1},$$
but passing the RHS to the LHS gives your identity.

Comment: Awesome, @Phicar! Thank you! Your idea has an interesting similarity with @RobPratt's.

Comment: @Valentino You are welcome. Yes indeed :).